# CSS Grid высота контейнера под количество элементов

Tags: html, css, style, css-grid

столкнулся с следующей проблемой:
Есть grid контейнер с установленными свойствами rows. Пока ячеек не больше 2х строк, контейнер подстраивается под них высотой, после - становится меньше, чем область которую занимают элементы.

Вот пример:

```css
.contacts_grid_container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-column-gap: 3.5%;
  grid-row-gap: 7.8%;
  grid-auto-rows: 18vw;
  grid-auto-columns: 25vw;
}

.contacts_grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px inset #ecc2ff;
}

.comment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: -220px;
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 500px; position: relative"> <!-- видимая область -->
  <div class="contacts_grid_container">
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment">
    .contacts_grid_container меньше <br>
    чем содержимое, WTF
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду признателен за содействие в поиске решения этой задачи.
Задача заключается в том, чтобы контейнер был **всегда** той высоты, какое место заполняют в нём его элементы, **вне зависимости от их количества**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решено - проблема была в том, что отступы между ячейками сетки были указаны в процентах.
Заодно "допёр" как сделать автоматическое заполнение сетки, чтобы не указывать каждый раз 
сколько строк. 
Вот пример, вдруг пригодится кому:

```css
.contacts_grid_container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-columns: 60px;
    grid-auto-rows: 115px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.contacts_grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 2px inset #ecc2ff;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width: 500px; position: relative"> <!-- видимая область -->
  <div class="contacts_grid_container">
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
    <div class="contacts_grid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```